# How to hide the Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date, bootstrap-datepicker

I made the date field readonly but still we are able to select the date from datepicker. 
I tried

```
$('#date').datepicker("None");
$('#date').datepicker("disable");
$('#date').datepicker("destroy");
```

None of them works.
But the below code worked partially. Like on click it is showing the calendar and getting hidden. I'm not able to select any date from the calendar. This is fine but even it should not show the calendar.

```
$('#date').on('click', function(){
    $('.datepicker').hide();
});
```

Comment: `.datepicker { display: none; }` ??

Comment: $('#endDate').datepicker().attr("disabled", true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the #date is readonly, why initialize the datepicker? The following code should be enough:
`$('#date').attr('readonly', true)`

EDITED to include the following solution to remove datepicker once it was initialized:
`$('#date').datepicker('remove');`

Comment: I'm not able to edit the field manually with this code. But one can pick another date value from the date picker . This is not what i want. Date picker should not be shown @user1928896

Comment: Then, this might do the trick `$('#date').datepicker('remove');`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
$('#date').hide();
```

Comment: This hides the whole date field . I want only datepicker to hide. I tried  
$('#date').datepicker().attr("disabled", true); But it is playing hide and seek game. Like it is displaying the datepicker and getting hidden.

Comment: Can you share your html too?

Answer (score 0):

Check the JSFiddle :- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymp5D/427/)

```
$('.myDatepicker').each(function() {
var $picker = $(this);
$picker.datepicker();

var pickerObject = $picker.data('datepicker');

//HIDE THE CALENDER
$picker.on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $picker.datepicker('hide');
});
});
```

Comment: I already tried this with on Click mentioned below $('#date').on('click', function(){$('.datepicker').hide();}); But it is displaying and hiding the datepicker. Somehow it is partially working , as im not able to select date from picker. But I want the datepicker to be hidden completly @Rushee

Comment: You want to select the date from datepicker, but the text box of date should be read only??

Comment: im not able to select date from picker. But I want the datepicker to be hidden completly. can you explain this.

Comment: I want to remove the datepicker completely. But on click of date field the datepicker calender is first shown and then hidden continuously(like a flip). Now i want it to be completly hidden on one go.It should not display and hide @ Rushee

Comment: My Usecase: There are two date fields date1 and date2 with datepickers. onChange of date1 value, date2 value has to be populated with with date1 value and should be readonly and it should not be editable. Somehow I made readonly true, and now trying to hide the datepicker @Rushee